# __le32 equivalent for 24 bits structure

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

Linux identifies little endian 32 bit types here [types.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/types.h#L170). I've to write an on-disk data structure as a C struct but one of the attribute is 24 bits. How do I represent it on the same lines?

Linux has __le32 and __le64, but nothing else for some other size.

Comment: On standard machines, there isn't any instruction dealing with 24bits data. So it must be a composed type. Could you give the type of your attribute ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the nearest larger type, i.e. `__le32`, and then write out the bytes individually. You should never write entire structures at once, since the compiler can (and will) add padding, which will vary with the compiler and architecture. Each field should be written as a unit to the file, so that you know the exact use of each byte in the output file.

Comment: Or even better, use a human-readable format like (sane) CSV or JSON.

Comment: I would be using 32bits in that case right? I need to conserve every byte coz of limited space.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use two different types: one for the in-memory representation and manipulation and one for the on-disk format.  The in-memory version uses simple type that are convenient for you (say uint32_t for an unsigned 24-bit value).  The on-disk representation can use arrays of uint8_t types.  Conversion routines are of course needed for this (which also isolates any conversion between little-endian and big-endian if applicable).

Here is a somewhat contrived example for illustration purposes.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t  version[3];

    uint8_t  options[2];
    uint8_t  data[3];
} my_type_disk;

typedef struct {            /* size of fields may diffe from disk version */
    uint32_t  version;      /* order may be different too */
    uint32_t  data;
    uint16_t  options;
} my_type_host;

void myTypeDiskToHost (my_type_disk *, my_type_host *);
void myTypeHostToDisk (my_type_host *, my_type_disk *);
```

Hope this helps.